Mitmproxy as a Transparent Proxy for HTTPS Requests
I am trying to set up a proxy server using mitmproxy that can handle HTTP endpoints and transparently forward requests to another proxy (Proxy B).
Here's what I need:

No requirement for clients to install certificates or validate self-signed certificates.
Allow "curl -x http://my-proxy:port https://www.example.com" to work, where the HTTPS handshake happens directly with the destination server (e.g., Example.com).
I don't need to decrypt or read the traffic. However, I want a log of the requests, such as the HTTP response code (e.g., 200) and possibly the size of the request.

What I Tried:
Regular Mode:
I managed to get it working partially. However, HTTPS requests fail due to certificate issues (since the mode isn't transparent and requires certificate installation).
Transparent Mode:
I attempted to set up a transparent proxy, but the configuration causes an infinite loop.
I tested this on both version 11 and version 10 of mitmproxy but encountered the same issue. I also opened an issue regarding this problem but haven't found a resolution yet.
https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/7369
Question
How can I configure mitmproxy to handle HTTPS requests transparently (with no certificate validation required on the client) and log the response details, such as status codes and request sizes? Are there specific configurations or alternative approaches to achieve this?
On some sites, I read about keeping the proxy in "regular" mode, removing the Host header, replacing it with the proxy's host, and then restoring the original Host header upon receiving the response. However, I couldn't make it work. Could you explain this approach in more detail?

"No requirement for clients to install certificates" Unless the TLS client implementation is defect TLS interception always requires installing the proxy root cert on client side. The only exception is if you only proxy servers you gave access to their private key.

TL;DR: what you want is not possible since there are contradicting requirements.


I don't need to decrypt or read the traffic. However, I want a log of the requests, such as the HTTP response code (e.g., 200) and possibly the size of the request.


These requirements contradict each other: since the HTTP request is fully (HTTP request and response header and body) encrypted inside the TLS connection it is essential to encrypt in order to get HTTP level details such as response code.


No requirement for clients to install certificates or validate self-signed certificates.


As stated in the last point it is necessary to decrypt in order to get to the HTTP level details. But decryption means that the proxy terminates the TLS connection and creates a new one. Since mitmproxy does not have the original servers certificate and private key it can only use its own certificate+key for this - which means that the client must trust these.
This means that logging HTTP level details will not work without installation of certificates in the client or having the client certificate validation disabled.

Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, something still doesn’t quite convince me. I tried doing something similar with Squid and Squidreport, using a very basic configuration with just "cache_peer." I can see bandwidth usage statistics and stats for proxied URLs (though not the full URL, only the domain, the date, and the response size). And I’m not using any certificate on the client. The problem with Squid is that it makes it difficult to call a webhook at the end of a request, which is why I’d prefer to use mitmproxy, as its modules make my life much easier

@Fabio: "(though not the full URL, only the domain, the date, and the response size)"* - destination domain is part of TLS handshake, thus visible without TLS termination unless Encrypted Client Hello is used. Date is simply the date when the connection happened, not some information out of the HTTP request, "Response size" is the amount of encrypted data received, which is the response size with some overhead due to TLS. But, you specifically asked for HTTP response code and this is only available after decryption since it is part of the (encrypted) HTTP response header.

Yes, you’re right—I wasn’t aware of that detail about TLS. Going back to the main question (and rephrasing it thanks to your valuable input): is it possible to obtain this information (response size including the handshake and the domain) for each individual request using mitmproxy?

@Fabio: If multiple requests are done inside the same HTTP connection (HTTP/1 keep-alive, HTTP/2 multiplexing) or if bidirectional websockets are used it is not possible to determine the size of individual responses. It might be possible to get this information from looking at the encrypted traffic with HTTP/1 keep-alive since requests are sequential and (contrary to HTTP/2) not overlapping, new requests are only send once response was received. But with keep-alive + pipelining it is again less visible. And I doubt that mitmproxy can do this, it is simply not the typical use case for it.

Got it, thanks for the clarification and for your time! :)
I need to make an API request that selects the proxy, performs the request, and then calls another endpoint to communicate (if possible) the destination site and total response size, what tool would you recommend? Squid doesn’t seem capable of doing this either

@Fabio: Unfortunately I have no recommendations here for you.
